# Video Streaming through FFMPEG library is very slow and it gets stuck after 1 or 2 minutes

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have used following code in build.gradle to get FFMPEG library.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaPlayer:1.0.3'
}
```

I am able to stream video but it is playing very slow and it gets stuck after 1-2 minutes playing.I googled and i found that i can set the frame rate but this library doesn't provide me any method to set frame rate.
As FFMPEG is very smooth so i need to use it.Please guide me.